# Ubuntu 15.04, "Disconnected - you are now offline"

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

I'm pretty new to ubuntu but here is the problem I have so far; my wireless connection seems to disconnect and reconnect itself. Some days it will work and somedays it will not.

I did some research online and from what I understand the (wireless?) driver I have currently, r8169 is bugged.

So far I have:

1. Blacklisted r8169 driver
2. Installed r8101 driver
3. Went onto /etc/modules and added the r8101 driver

However it is still to no avail.

Here is some information that might help:

```
##### lspci #############################
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: 
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
Subsystem: Dell Device 05ee
Kernel driver in use: r8101

##### iwconfig ##########################
eth0      no wireless extensions.
usb0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.

##### /etc/modules ######################
lp
r8101
```

Interestingly enough I found out that messing around with the charging cable  sometimes influences whether or not I have wifi.